# Subtracting two cell in Excel but only when identified by a label

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to subtract two cells in Excel only when the adjacent cell, Cell `H10` has a text label of **Hm1**, Cell `I10` has a value of **5000**. Cell `H12` has a text label of **HM2**, Cell `I12` has a value of **6000**.

```
    H    I                   H    I
10 HM1 5000              10 HM1 5000
11 FDL 5050      or      11 HQ  5025
12 HM2 6000              12 FLD 5050
                         13 FLD 5075
                         14 HM2 6000
```

I need the formula to always subtract looking at values in HM2 - HM1.

How do I accomplish this?

I have Microsoft Excel 2013

Comment: Do you have HM1 or HM2 more than once?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to substract the values of I where the code of H are HM2 and HM1 ?

Answer (score 0):

If HM1 and HM2 occur only once you can use:
`=SUM(--(H10:H14="HM2")*(I10:I14),-(--(H10:H14="HM1")*I10:I14)))`

Array formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time

Change the reference H10:H14 and I10:I14 to correspond your Data

If you have two columns with repeated HM1 and HM2 and each time HM1 appear to write the result you can use in J10:
`=IF(H10="HM1",IFERROR(INDEX(I11:$I$17,MATCH("HM2",H11:$H$17,0),1)-I10,""),"")`
The formula will test if H10="HM1" it will look in the remaining cell for HM2 and subtract the corresponding Values I